# Operate on a list and replace values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the list called **'list_one'**, which I seek to relate to **'list_relation'**, to finally have a final list of values, my logic is as follows:

By looping in the range of **'list_one'** and for each **'items_relation'** of **'list_relation'**:

1.If **'list_one [i] [0]'** is inside **'items_relation'**, I add the corresponding operation of **'list_one'**.

```
list_one = [[1,      0], 
             [2,     0], 
             [3,     0],
             [4,     0], 
             [11,    0], 
             [12,    0], 
             [13, 2000], 
             [14, 3000], 
             [15, 3500], 
             [16, 5000], 
             [17, 6500], 
             [18, 8800], 
             [19, 6700],
             [20,  280]]

# Code to get this 'list_relation' ...

list_relation = [[13, 14], [15, 16], 
                 [17, 18], [19, 20]]
             
final = []
for i in range(len(list_one)):
    for items_elements in list_relation:
        for k in items_elements:
            if list_one[i][0] in items_elements:
                final.append((list_one[i][1] + list_one[i][0]))  
print(final)
```

I am looking for a list like this:

```
[[2013, 3014], [3515, 5016], [6517, 8818], [6719, 300]]
```

What is the best way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list_one` appears to be a lookup table - it would make more sense to use a dictionary instead of a list. Then loop through the values of `list_relation`, do a lookup against the dictionary and add the value if it is there. If it isn't there, get a default value of `0` so it doesn't affect the sum. This also means there is no need to include lookup entries with values of `0`:

```
list_one = {13: 2000,  # note choose a better var name
            14: 3000, 
            15: 3500, 
            16: 5000, 
            17: 6500, 
            18: 8800, 
            19: 6700,
            20: 280,}

list_relation = [[13, 14], 
                 [15, 16], 
                 [17, 18], 
                 [19, 20]]

final = [[item + list_one.get(item, 0) 
          for item in pair] 
         for pair in list_relation]
```

Comment: The solution is very good, but what happens is that I have more columns in my 'list_one', so for me the solution that I think is most convenient is through lists since that way it is easier to access them below. So I would like to know if the same can be done with lists. @Dan

Comment: Then I suggest you add a more realistic example. It may be that you should look at a pandas dataframe. Otherwise maybe a dictionary where the values are tuples. But looking up a value in a list is much slower than looking up a value in a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution and for the suggestion on the use of dictionaries. Best regards. @Dan

Answer (score 2):

You can build a dictionary from `list_one` and then iterate to create the resulting list.

```
>>> d = dict(list_one)
>>> final = [[el+d[el] for el in l] for l in list_relation]
>>> final
[[2013, 3014], [3515, 5016], [6517, 8818], [6719, 300]]
```

Comment: I would like to know if it can be done but with lists, because I have more data in my 'list_one' (more columns), for manageability reasons @abc.